# Question about k closest points to origin using std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> kClosest(vector<vector<int>>& points, int K) {
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        map<double, vector<int>, greater<int>> rMap;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            int num = ((points[i][0])*(points[i][0])) + ((points[i][1])*(points[i][1]));
            double temp = sqrt(num);
            if (rMap.size() < K) {
                rMap.insert(pair<double, vector<int>>(temp, points[i]));
            }
            else {
                map<double, vector<int>>::iterator it = rMap.begin();
                if (it->first > temp) {
// rMap size seems to be fine
                    rMap.erase(rMap.find(it->first));
//rMap size still seems to be fine
                    rMap.insert(pair<double, vector<int>>(temp, points[i]));
// rMap size is the same as before the insert
// new pair is also not inserted
                }
            }
        }
        for (map<double, vector<int>>::iterator it = rMap.begin(); it != rMap.end(); it++) {
            result.push_back(it->second);
        }        
        return result;
    }
};
```

I made some inline comments. Why does the map::insert not add the element to the map here? I am not looking for alternative solutions. I just want to know the reason for the behavior.

This doesn't work:

Your input:[[3,3],[5,-1],[-2,4]]
2

Output:[[3,3]]

Expected:[[3,3],[-2,4]]

But this works: 
Your input:[[68,97],[34,-84],[60,100],[2,31],[-27,-38],[-73,-74],[-55,-39],[62,91],[62,92],[-57,-67]]
5

Output:[[34,-84],[-57,-67],[-55,-39],[-27,-38],[2,31]]

Expected:[[2,31],[-27,-38],[-55,-39],[-57,-67],[34,-84]]

Comment: did you check the result of `insert`? it will return the iterator of the newly inserted element or the element that prevented insertion.

Comment: yes, it is weird i am trying this on leetcode and leetcode says the vector being inserted [-2, 4] is already present in the map and the iterator returned points to [3,3]. The sqrt of the two are 4.2 and 4.1 respectively. I wonder if there is anything wrong with some internal casting?